# Is row created timestamp is unique in a table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10, postgresql-11

I know that timestamp is a instance of time at a moment.

But coming to my table, my table doesn't have the primary key.

So i need a unique column for transactions.

Shall i take row created timestamp column has unique column of table.

Table Definition

```
Create Table order_processing_logs(
    order_number integer,
    processing_status integer,
    cust_id character varying(200),
    vendor_id character varying(200),
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .,etc,
    created_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now(),
    updated_time timestamp without time zone DEFAULT now()
);
```

Shall i take created_time as unique column in table.

Right now if i changed the architecture of table it will effect the millions of records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Normally, you cannot be sure that there are no two rows that come in exactly the same time.

It would be more critical if you are using **transactions** where all rows are committed at the same time. This fiddle shows that the timestamps are equals for two rows: [demo: db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=517b3bfe6bfa2b8fb97d66ccf531df57)

Maybe you could use a combination of two columns as

```
PRIMARY KEY (order_number, current_timestamp)
```

But since you are not ensuring the uniqueness of each of the columns (or the combination) you would never be safe.

---

It is always better to add a column with type `serial` which is an automatically increasing (`bigint`)number.

Since **Postgres 10** you could use the `GENERATE IDENTITY` instead of `serial` type:

```
id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
```

(http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-identity-column/)

Comment: timestamp means that in milliseconds also count naa

Comment: then what will be best approach without primary key or unique column

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar That means, it would be a great chance of uniqueness but it is not 100% safe. What about transactions that are committed at the same time.

Comment: @RatanUdayKumar This fiddle shows the transaction problem

Comment: maybe i have to use combination of another column with created_time

Answer (score 2):

i don't think it would be wise just by using created_time because 2 different order may place in same time

i prefer combination of `order_number,created_time` column for making unique

Comment: timestamp means that in milliseconds also count naa

Comment: then what will be the best approach without primary key or unique column

Comment: there is very light difference between unique key and primary key ,so in your case you can create one of them